# Reformatting Tab-Separated Data in Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, csv

I have some tab-separated data in Excel that needs to be reformatted to work in Tableau. Here's what it looks like:

```
State   2001    2002    2003    2004    2005    2006    2007
Alabama 5.6 5.71    5.88    6.08    6.46    7.07    7.57
Alaska  10.54   10.46   10.5    10.99   11.72   12.84   13.28
Arizona 7.27    7.21    7.34    7.45    7.79    8.24    8.54
Arkansas    6.05    5.61    5.57    5.67    6.3 6.99    6.96
```

Here's how I need it to look:

```
State   Cost    Date
Alabama 5.6 12/31/2001
Alabama 5.71    12/31/2002
Alabama 5.88    12/31/2003
Alabama 6.08    12/31/2004
Alabama 6.46    12/31/2005
Alabama 7.07    12/31/2006
Alabama 7.57    12/31/2007
Alaska  10.54   12/31/2001
Alaska  10.46   12/31/2002
Alaska  10.5    12/31/2003
Alaska  10.99   12/31/2004
Alaska  11.72   12/31/2005
Alaska  12.84   12/31/2006
Alaska  13.28   12/31/2007
Arizona 7.27    12/31/2001
Arizona 7.21    12/31/2002
Arizona 7.34    12/31/2003
Arizona 7.45    12/31/2004
Arizona 7.79    12/31/2005
Arizona 8.24    12/31/2006
Arizona 8.54    12/31/2007
Arkansas    6.05    12/31/2001
Arkansas    5.61    12/31/2002
Arkansas    5.57    12/31/2003
Arkansas    5.67    12/31/2004
Arkansas    6.3 12/31/2005
Arkansas    6.99    12/31/2006
Arkansas    6.96    12/31/2007
```

What would be the best way to achieve this in Python? I'm familiar with Numpy and Pandas so those are options, but what I really want is just for Python to spit out the reformatted data so that I can paste into Excel easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Pandas I'd do it this way:

Assuming you have the following DataFrame (read from Excel):

```
In [99]: df
Out[99]:
      State   2001   2002   2003   2004   2005   2006   2007
0   Alabama   5.60   5.71   5.88   6.08   6.46   7.07   7.57
1    Alaska  10.54  10.46  10.50  10.99  11.72  12.84  13.28
2   Arizona   7.27   7.21   7.34   7.45   7.79   8.24   8.54
3  Arkansas   6.05   5.61   5.57   5.67   6.30   6.99   6.96
```

Solution:

```
In [102]: d = pd.melt(df, 'State', var_name='Date', value_name='Cost')

In [103]: d.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(d['Date'])+pd.offsets.YearEnd())
Out[103]:
       State       Date   Cost
0    Alabama 2001-12-31   5.60
1     Alaska 2001-12-31  10.54
2    Arizona 2001-12-31   7.27
3   Arkansas 2001-12-31   6.05
4    Alabama 2002-12-31   5.71
5     Alaska 2002-12-31  10.46
6    Arizona 2002-12-31   7.21
7   Arkansas 2002-12-31   5.61
8    Alabama 2003-12-31   5.88
9     Alaska 2003-12-31  10.50
..       ...        ...    ...
18   Arizona 2005-12-31   7.79
19  Arkansas 2005-12-31   6.30
20   Alabama 2006-12-31   7.07
21    Alaska 2006-12-31  12.84
22   Arizona 2006-12-31   8.24
23  Arkansas 2006-12-31   6.99
24   Alabama 2007-12-31   7.57
25    Alaska 2007-12-31  13.28
26   Arizona 2007-12-31   8.54
27  Arkansas 2007-12-31   6.96

[28 rows x 3 columns]
```

you can also easily save it as Excel file:

```
d.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(d['Date'])+pd.offsets.YearEnd()) \
 .to_excel(r'/path/to/output.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! The only issue I'm having with this is that the dates all return as 1970-12-31 for some reason. Otherwise, that's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You asked how to do it directly in Python,
so it would be something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
inputname  = 'Excel.txt'
outputname  = 'Tableau.txt'

with open( filename, 'r' ) as text:
  container = []
  for line in text:
    l = line.split()
    name = l[0]
    if name == 'State':
      dates = l
    else:
      end = len(l) -1
      for e in range(1, end):
        date = dates[e]
        cost = l[e]
        container.append(name, '12/31/' +date, cost)

with open(outputname, 'w') as out:
  stringified = '\n' .join(container)
  out.write(stringified)
```